# How to limit number of kernels in grub

Tags: boot, grub2, kernel

As said in the question, i have grub with the 3 latest kernels installed, so i can choose between them in boot time.
The problem is that latest kernel 5.15 is very heavy  and i dont have enough space in /boot no more...so id like to reduce to two.
I cant remember where i have to put this limit in ubuntu 20.04

Also id like how can i update my kernel 5.15 in ubuntu 20.04 ( i had to install it manually downloading a .deb package, as 5.15 still is not avalaible in 20.04)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Normally an Ubuntu system will have one default kernel and one older kernel as a fallback.

If you have two old kernels (= three in total), you can usually automatically remove the oldest one with this command:

```
sudo apt autoremove
```

Alternatively, you can look in /lib/modules (with the command `ls /lib/modules`) to see which kernel versions are installed, and manually remove the one you don't need with the following command (replacing `KERNELVERSION` with the version found in /lib/modules):

```
sudo apt remove linux-image-KERNELVERSION
```

If the kernel headers are installed alongside the kernel itself, they can also be removed like this:

```
sudo apt remove linux-headers-KERNELVERSION
```

Be careful not to remove your currently running kernel though (found through the command `uname -r`).

For your second question, although I don't personally run Ubuntu 20.04, I believe kernel 5.15 is in the Focal repos, https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/kernel/linux-image-5.15.0-33-generic. If this is not possible to install with `apt`, downloading the DEB package and installing it directly should be fine, but just be aware it probably won't auto-update or be autoremoved by the `apt autoremove` command.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I use Ansible to maintain my systems. I have a playbook that updates the kernel, and after the kernel is updated I have Ansible run this one-line bash script:

```
for f in $(apt-mark showmanual | grep linux-); do apt-mark auto $f; done; apt-get -y autoremove --purge
```

That removes all but the two latest kernels, which are the two linked to `vmlinuz` and `vmlinuz.old`.